# Simplemodal: Form Submit vs Close in iFrame

Tags: javascript, jquery, simplemodal

Got a popup legal notice inside an simplemodal window (iframe) that's working exactly as I expect it to. There's a form in the iframe that when you submit it, the modal window closes and you continue on to your destination - in this case, a "mailto:" link.

Problem is - I need a separate "close" function that doesn't open the mailto link, just closes the modal. Currently, submitting the form OR clicking the "close" link both open the "mailto" link.

What I've got so far:

Inside my iFrame to handle the form submit:

```
    $('#alertFORM').submit(function() {
    window.parent.jQuery.modal.close(true);
});
```

And my functions handling everything else:

```
$('.legalnotice').on('click', function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
var src = "email_alert.html";
var mailto = $(this).attr('href');

$.modal('<iframe src="' + src + '" height="400" width="390" style="border:0" id="legalFRAME">', {
    closeHTML: "<a href='#'>Close</a>",
    closeCLASS: "simplemodal-close",
    containerId: "modal",
    containerCss: {
        backgroundColor: "#f8f8f8",
        borderColor: "#f8f8f8",
        height: 500,
        padding: 0,
        width: 400
    },
    overlayClose: true,
    onClose: function (dialog) {
        $.modal.close();
        window.location.href = mailto;
    }
});
```

});
});

I believe I understand the problem - both the form submit and the 'close' link call the onClose function. Haven't quite figured out ow to seperate the two yet so only the form submit opens the 'mailto' link.

I've tried changing the code in my iFrame:

```
    $('#alertFORM').submit(function() {
    parent.closeModal();
});
```

... and then back on the parent page at the top of my javascript above:

```
function closeModal() {
$("#modal").dialog("close");
```

}

... but that doesn't work.

Actively working on it. Suggestions most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Got it finally! Inside the file in my iFrame:

```
 $('#alertFORM').submit(function() {
    window.showEmail = "true";
    window.parent.jQuery.modal.close(true);
});

 $( ".modalCloseImg" ).on('click', function (e) {
    window.parent.jQuery.modal.close(true);
});
```

... and back on the parent page:

```
onClose: function (dialog) {
        window.redirectEmail = window.legalFRAME.showEmail;
        if(window.redirectEmail == "true")
        {               
            window.location.href = mailto;
            window.legalFRAME.showEmail = "false";
            window.redirectEmail = "false";
        }
        $.modal.close();            
    }
```